# JQuery Mobile 1.4.5 icons do not display on Adobe Air

Tags: jquery-mobile, air

I am using jquery mobile in Adobe Air.

When I updated jquery mobile to 1.4.5, I found the icons are disappear.

I testing in a very simple html, when using jquery.mobile-1.1.2.css, the icons work well, but when changing to jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css the icons disappear as shown in the screenshots.

I have checked the 1.4.5 icons file, they are in images/icons-png.

I use too many features of 1.4.5 to switch back to 1.1.2.

The questions are:
How can I fix the missing icons in 1.4.5?
What are some tips for debugging this myself?

I usually debug in Chrome, but this works in Chrome.

I am testing air OSX; my air CFBundleVersion is 18.0.0.180

```
<html> 
<head> 
   <title>Hello World</title> 

   <script src="AIRAliases.js" type="text/javascript"></script>




   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile.js"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.1.2.css"/>
   <!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.1.2.css"/-->
   <!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css"/-->
</head> 
<body> 
   <h1>Hello World</h1> 

   <div id="informationPage" data-role="page">
         <div data-role="header">
            <h1> 1.1.2 </h1>
         </div>
         <div data-role="content">
            <select id="heightDropdown">
               <option value="408">Here is 1.1.2.css</option>
               <option value="409">4'9"</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body> 
</html>
```

[image: Side by side screenshots of missing icon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for the asker.

The problem come from AIR don't support SVG icons which have brought in since jQuery Mobile 1.4.0  and use as default format.

To use png icons as default format.  Download jquery.mobile-1.4.5.zip from 
jQuery Mobile site.  Then use jquery.mobile.inline-png.css or jquery.mobile.external-png.css replace jquery.mobile.css.  If use jquery.mobile.external-png.css, make sure copy images folder too.